# Triggering ng-show works only with ng-click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, socket.io

I want to bind a variable to `ng-show` and right now it works only with click event. For example i work with `socket.io` and i want that when server send a message to client, that variable changes and then triggers `ng-show` but its not work! only if i click and trigger `ng-click` event, i that desired binding works. what's the problem?

this is my controller, in this code i catch server message and console.log works and print TRUE, but there is nothing in `ng-show`. Next time i click the button, it works! i can't understand why

```
app.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope){
$scope.loading=false;
$scope.socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

$scope.getNewEvent = function(){
    $scope.socket.emit('getNewEvent');
};

//here i catch server messages
$scope.socket.on('setNewEvent', function(data){
    $scope.loading = true; //loading variable changes but not effects ng-show
    console.log($scope.loading);
});
});
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<div class="loading" ng-show="loading">Loading... {{loading}}</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply scope changes because Angular doesn't know anything about changes made to model by socket event (it happens from "outside" of Angular digest lifecycle):

```
$scope.socket.on('setNewEvent', function(data){
    $scope.loading = true;
    $scope.$apply();
});
```